# XPath: Get node below another node

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm new to XPath, and I need to get the table node after the following:

```
<p><b>Some unique string</b></p>

<center><table>
<tr>
<th>.....
```

I have been trying things such as:

```
"following-sibling::.//p//b[.='Some unique string']"
".//p//b[.='Some unique string']/following:://table"
```

So far I've managed to get rather stuck and confused, would greatly appreciate a pointer in the right direction. So thank you in advance :)

(If it makes a difference, I'm using the lxml.html module in Python 2.6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath 1.0 expression:

```
//b[.='Some unique string']/following::table[1]
```

Meaning: *the first following `table` element of any `b` element in the whole document having 'Some unique string' as string value*